# How to load Dashboard default media files via HTTPS even when Browser URL has HTTP

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script

**How to load Dashboard default media files via HTTPS even when Browser AddressBar URL has HTTP**

On all Admin Dashboard pages, I want to force the loading of all CSS, JS via https, even when URL in browser addressbar is using http.

Can this be done?

Currently, I have tried to hardcode in wp-login.php the default list of media files. This loads the hardcoded CSS/JS files via https even when its HTTP in Browser URL.

But, I cant go further into complex structure of wp-admin/ admin-header.php

I'm now looking into trying enqueue in my theme's function.php

```
/*Enqueue Admin CSS JS */
function wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script( $hook ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'default1', 'https://example.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&amp;dir=ltr&amp;load%5B%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,wp-pointer,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,widgets&amp;load%5B%5D=,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check&amp;ver=5.2.6', array(), '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'default2', 'https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/css/style.css?ver=1591072501', array(), '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'default3', 'https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/css/wf-font-awesome.1587658822.css?ver=7.4.7', array(), '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'default4', 'https://example.com/plugins/wordfence/css/wf-global.1587658822.css?ver=7.4.7', array(), '1.0' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script' );
```

PS: Media files discussed above are default System+Plugin CSS/JS files (and **not** custom css/js file)

PS: I dont want to force HTTPS in Browser AddressBar, only force HTTPS for the included media files.

Comment: Have you tried setting `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`? I've honestly never had this problem because I force https for wp-admin (and rest of the page), is this not an option?

Comment: @kero i **dont want to force https in AddressBar**. If I add `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` then it forces https in AddressBar